# Identify this image backup format

Tags: linux, backup

I need to use an old backup, but feeling ashamed I cannot remember which utility I used to create it. Please is anybody able to identify this backup format? This is list of all files in my backup folder:

```
08.04.2014  17:44                 4 Cisty-system-08-04-2014.backup
08.04.2014  17:44            32 768 Cisty-system-08-04-2014.mbr
08.04.2014  17:44               251 Cisty-system-08-04-2014.sfdisk
08.04.2014  17:44                14 Cisty-system-08-04-2014.size
08.04.2014  17:47     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.000
08.04.2014  17:49     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.001
08.04.2014  17:51     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.002
08.04.2014  17:54     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.003
08.04.2014  17:56     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.004
08.04.2014  17:59     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.005
08.04.2014  18:01     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.006
08.04.2014  18:03     2 147 483 648 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.007
08.04.2014  18:06     1 822 069 003 Cisty-system-08-04-2014_part4.008
```

The .backup file contains only sda4 which is probably partition location, the file .sfdisk contains (surprisingly) an output of sfdisk utility.

Thank you for your suggestions :)

Klasyc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is FSArchiver or PartImage? See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSArchiver) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Finally it turned out that it is [Redo Backup](http://redobackup.org/) image. Shodanshok, thank you for your suggestions.